# Apache unexpectedly lost all idle processes

Tags: apache, idle-processing

Sometimes in apache happens that all idle processes are lost. Apache continue running, but every request takes too much time. After a few minutes is everything ok without restarting.

In the server there is 512 GB RAM and at the time there was 150 GB RAM free. So it wasn't the case where system would kill it because of RAM.

Can you please give me advice, why it happens?

[image: Apache processes munin]